# is 1hr 15 minutes enough time to change terminals at Manila?

Tags: connecting-flights, manila

My flight from Osaka to Manila is from 13:45-17:00 on Jetstar airline. I am planning to book another flight from Manila to Tacloban the same day at 18:15. It's the last flight going to tacloban on Cebu Pacific airline. If I book it, will I be able to make it from terminal 1 to terminal 3? Should I book it or just book the next day earliest flight?

Answer (score 11):

Book a flight the next day. Taking the 1815 flight gives you 75 minutes to get off the plane, pass through immigration, collect your bags, check in, pass through security and get on the next flight.  Also note that you will have to re-check your bags before check-in closes, which is typically somewhere between 30 and 60 minutes before departure. That could leave you very little time.

I don't know Manila airport but I wouldn't try to do that anywhere in the world. If your incoming flight is late, you have even less time.  Further, because the two flights are on separate tickets, Cebu Pacific would have no requirement to put you on a later flight if you missed the connection: it's your responsibility to get to the airport on time and the airline doesn't care if you're coming from Osaka or downtown Manila.

Comment: Seconded.  If you are going to attempt a tight connection, Manila is not the place to do it.

Comment: This is generally good advice, with one exception. If the domestic flight is sufficiently cheap at short notice (often the case in SE Asia), it might make more sense to take a chance at making the tight connection, rather than to choose the guaranteed loss of time and money that comes with choosing a safe, next-day flight.

Comment: @dbkk That's interesting to know. In this case, the second flight would surely have to be _very_ cheap, given the high probability of missing it.

Comment: An important point: with checked luggage, the passenger needs to have deplaned, gone through immigration, claimed bags, gone through customs, gone to the other terminal, found the check-in/baggage drop desk, queued, and dropped bags **before the check-in/baggage drop deadline**. Too lazy to check what that is for Cebu Pacific, but in most cases it ranges between 40 and 60 minutes before departure, which would leave 15 to 35 minutes to do all of the above. Not familiar with Manila airport, but that seems impossible to me. And that’s considering the first flight is on time...

Comment: @jcaron Good point, thanks.  I added it to the answer.

Comment: @DavidRicherby In this case, it looks like the second flight is indeed *very* cheap: only $36.

Answer (score 3):

Based on my experience from flying through Manila many times in the last 10 years you are really cutting it tight.

Because you need to go through immigrations and also fetch your bags, re check in for your transit most likely etc

I am a betting man and I would lay 5-1 that you would miss the fight meaning I think you have less than 20% chance of making it, a lot of things have to go really right for you to have a chance.